# What algorithm can sort the first $\sqrt n$ elements of an array in $O(n)$ time?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I want to partially sort an array of $n$ elements to get the first $\sqrt{n}$ elements sorted, and it has to be done in $O(n)$ time.

The complexity $O(n)$ seems to imply that it is necessary to go through the entire array, but when using a sorting algorithm in the first step of building a tree/heap by using heap sort, this and other $O(n\log n)$ algorithms are the fastest they can be when processing the entire $n$ elements.

Does this mean that I don't have to process all the numbers, and what kind of strategy can I use?

Comment: I don't see the problem here, you have an array with m=sqrt(n) elements, so you can sort it in O(m ln m) = O(sqrt(n) ln(n) ) that is under O(n)... did I miss something?

Comment: There are n elements in the array and it's unsorted, and I want to get the first sqrt(n) sorted elements from it.

Comment: It's tstill unclear to what you want exactly : do you want to sort the sqrt(n) biggest (or smallest) elements? something else?

Comment: I want to get the first $\sqrt{n}$ elements of its sorted version, so smallest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it can be done.

First of all,
you have to look at
all $n$ items.

Then,
you have to keep the top
$\sqrt{n}$ items.
To find where an item
that is in the top $\sqrt{n}$ places,
you have to do 
$O(\log(\sqrt{n}))
=O(\log(n))
$
comparisons.
If the items are
badly ordered,
you will have to do this
$n$ times.

This gives a worst case time
of $O(n \log n)$.

If the items are
will distributed,
the placing in the top $\sqrt{n}$
might only be done
$\sqrt{n}$ times.
In this case,
the placing would only take
$O(\sqrt{n}\log(n))$
operations,
so this would be
$O(n)$.

Comment: Is it possible not to look through the entire array but just one half of the array each time such that it adds up to roughly n? This is a homework problem.

Comment: I don't think so. You have to look at all elements. Suppose that the items are in decreasing order (assuming that you want the smallest items). Then the items you want are at the end. Do you have to get $O(n)$?

Comment: Yes, I have to get $O(n)$

Comment: You might take a look at the algorithm for finding the k-th best item. It has a O(n) time for fixed k. If it can be done with $k = \sqrt{n}$ in time O(n), then one additional pass can get the top $\sqrt{n}$ in O(n).

Comment: Aha! Look up quickselect here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Answer (score 4):

1. Use **Quickselect** to find the $k=\sqrt{(N)}$-th element (Quickselect works exactly like Quicksort, but only recurses in one side, the side in which the index $k$ is, while Quicksort recurses in both sides). It will take $O(N)$ in average case.
2. For finding the $k$-th element, Quickselect has to partition the input. Thus, after Quickselect found the $k$-th element, all other elements to the left are  $\leq k$ (but not sorted) and all other elements to the right are $\geq k$ and not sorted.
   Because of this, the first $k$ elements can now be sorted using a normal sorting algorithm like Quicksort or Heapsort. It will take $O(k\cdot \log_2 (k))$ time additionally in average case, which is far smaller than $N$.

- Note that Quickselect and Quicksort both have $O(N^2)$ worst case. Quickselect has $O(N)$ average case and Quicksort $O(N\cdot \log_2(N))$ average case. Methods exist with $O(N)$ worst case for selecting the $k$-th element, but they have high constant factors and are slower because of this. It is also not clear if they partition the input as good as Quickselect and Heapselect (Heapselect partition is the heap). But this would be required for the next step of your problem.
- In your specific case with $k=\sqrt{N}$, it is possible to use **HeapSelect** that for this $k$ has an average case of $O(N)$ and requires $\lt N\cdot \log_2(k)$ comparisons in worst case where the heap grows only until size $k$. After the heap has size $k$, an element will only be put into the heap if it is smaller than the current maximum element. For small $k$ like $k\leq\sqrt{N}$, this is probably even faster than Quickselect, because after a short time the heap can compare most elements in $O(1)$ time by just comparing the current element with the root node of the heap and the majority will be bigger than because you only want the smallest $\sqrt{N}$ elements, those elements are only compared once and the elements are not copied/moved here. Thus, it could be an interesting comparison to the Quickselect method.

**Testing with Heapselect**

In the following, I show a Rust code for your specific problem. We can observe $O(N)$ average case behaviour for $k=\sqrt{N}$. But it has $O(N\cdot\log_2(k))$ worst case. For simplicity I used am external memory heap, but it could also [use](https://github.com/sundy-li/partial_sort) internal memory. I'm wondering, what is the highest $k$ where the algorithm is still fast...

For $k=\sqrt{N}$, Heapselect is nearly three times faster than Quickselect.

```
use std::{collections::BinaryHeap, time::Instant};

/*
fastrand = "2.0.1"
*/

fn main() {
    let N: usize = 100_000_000;
    let k = (N as f64).sqrt() as usize;


    // best case (ascending): let mut a: Vec<usize> = Vec::from_iter((0..N));
    // worst case (descending): let mut a: Vec<usize> = Vec::from_iter((0..N).rev());
    // average case (randomized):
    let mut a: Vec<usize> = Vec::from_iter((0..N));
    fastrand::shuffle(&mut a);
    let mut heap: BinaryHeap<usize> = BinaryHeap::with_capacity(k);

    let now = Instant::now();

    let mut number_log_n_calls: usize = 0;

    for &e in a.iter().take(k) {
        heap.push(e);
    }

    for &e in a.iter().skip(k) {
        if let Some(&root_node) = heap.peek() {
            if root_node > e {
                heap.pop();
                number_log_n_calls += 1;
                heap.push(e);
            }
        }
    }

    let mut smallest_k_elements = heap.into_vec();
    //smallest_k_elements.sort_unstable();
    let runtime = now.elapsed();
    //println!("{:?}", smallest_k_elements);
    println!("number_log_n_calls={:?}; N={:?}; k=sqrt(N)={:?}; runtime={:?}", number_log_n_calls, N, k, runtime);
}
```

Comment: There is also a O(n + k log n) solution based on heap sort. First heapify as usual, and perform heap sort until there are k sorted elements.

Comment: In your proposed method, the "First heapify as usual" is already slower than my whole method (in average case) because you heapify all N elements and I only heapify all k elements. Most of the other N-k elements are compared once without an additional operation while your heapify does data element moves per element and more comparisons per element in average.